# scrapy css selector - get text from sub elements

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

The page i'm trying to crawl has an element like this. And i want to get the entire text within the div.

```
<div class="OrganicTitle-LinkText organic__url-text">
    <b>Bitcoin</b> - Open source P2P money
</div>
```

The Selector that i'm currently using, is 
`response.css("div.OrganicTitle-LinkText.organic__url-text::text").get()`
But it seems to have ignored the text inside `<b></b>` 
And the result i'm getting is  `- Open source P2P money`
I want to get the entire text using css selectors only (because changing to xpath would require a lot of code alterations)
It won't be  problem even if the `<b></b>` tags are fetched in the results as they can be easily removed by using regular expressions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem?

Comment: This should work `' '.join(response.css("[class^='OrganicTitle-LinkText'] ::text").getall()).strip()`

Comment: To get all the following text elements you need a space before `::text`. Then you can `join` and `strip` to get the text you want as one: `"".join(response.css(".organic__url-text ::text").getall()).strip()`

Comment: @SIM, your solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: @tomjn, your solution worked too. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I'd try this:

```
response.css("div.OrganicTitle-LinkText.organic__url-text::text").extract()
```

or this:

```
response.css("div.OrganicTitle-LinkText.organic__url-text").extract()
```

Comment: Did not work.
```(...::text).extract()``` returned ```[<div class=\"OrganicTitle-LinkText organic__url-text\"><b>Bitcoin</b> - Open source P2P money</div>]``` and the second one gave ```[ - Open source P2P money]```